# Import Highcharts module SvgRenderer failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I use a Angular4 with Type script and need import highchart module in component because need add a custom icon in symbols SvgRenderer like this:

```
Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.custom = function (x, y, w, h) {


      var path = [

          'M', x + w * 0.5, y,
          'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
          // Arrow head
          'M', x + w * 0.3, y + h * 0.5,
          'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
          'L', x + w * 0.7, y + h * 0.5,

      ];
      return path;
  };
```

i try with

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

And i get:

```
  /node_modules/@types/highcharts/index"' has no default export.
```

i try with

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

And i get a

```
 Property 'SVGRenderer' does not exist on type 'Static'.
```

Comment: How about loading any module e.g. exporting? If that works then you could set up the custom code the same way and load as a plugin.

Comment: i will ned clean Property 'SVGRenderer' does not exist on type 'Static'. error into console im using angular 4 with highchart a i drawing a svg icon with highchart function   Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download  = function(xxxx)

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer my question and is not about my suggestion. The limitation comes from Angular, so a it's more general Angular issue rather than a Highcharts issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `(Highcharts as any).SVGRenderer`
Not clean but you it's a workaround

Otherwise you can

```js
import {Renderer} from 'highcharts'

Renderer.prototype.symbols.custom = ...
```